# Why doesn't JpaRepository have a saveAll method in Spring Data Jpa?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm extending JpaRepository in my code and I can't use the saveAll method even though it is in CrudRepository, which is extended by PagingAndSortingRepository, which is in turn extended by JpaRepository.

When I try to use the method as `repository.saveAll(someIterable)` my IDE can't find it, and if I try to override it in my repository interface as below I still get an error saying that the method doesn't override a method from a superclass.

```
@Override
Iterable<MyEntity> saveAll(Iterable<MyEntity> d);
```

Trying to compile obviously gives a compilation error. Anybody knows why?

Comment: It's there, like you said - CrudRepository has it. Are you not extending some other JpaRepository by example?

Comment: I am having the same issue here... What dhave you done to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

`saveAll()` was not included in v1 of `spring-data-jpa` and didn't make its way into Spring Boot until March 2018 with the `2.0.0` release. Check your dependencies; you're likely using an older version.

Answer (score 0):

`JpaRepository` overrides the `saveAll()` method to return a `List` instead of an `Iterable`:

In `CrudRepository`:

```
<S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> var1);
```

In `JpaRepository`:

```
<S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);
```

Comment: Trying to add an Override annotation still gives an error and I can't use the method unless I actually type it in my repository (without the annotation)

Comment: Can you edit your question and some more code? Show us the repository code and the code that uses it. Also the exact error you get.

Comment: The one in the question is the only code in the repository and even replacing Iterable with List at the beginning of the signature gives a plain "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype" compilation error

Comment: So you have `public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity>` and you inject a `MyEntityRepository` somewhere and that reference does not allow you to call `saveAll`? I would suggest you setup a test project that shows this behaviour so we can see what is going on exactly.